# Interface, System.Schedulable, relationship must be maintained: org deployment error

Tags: apex, managed-package, scheduled-apex

I am deploying code to 1st generation packaging org. The deployment steps we follow is:

1. Convert the code base to metadata api format from sfdx format
2. Execute the command to deploy the code to packaging org

However I am seeing the error this time related to schedulable classes: `Interface, System.Schedulable, relationship must be maintained:` which I haven't seen earlier. I searched around a bit for the error, but no information is available.

Is there any recent changes wrt to Schedulable classes which is causing this issue?
Thanks in advance for your thoughts/suggestions.

**Update:**
In fact, we are seeing the issue with few of the standard Apex interfaces

```
InstallHandler
Schedulable
Comparable
```

with same error as mentioned above.

**Another Update:**
Salesforce has accepted this was a bug and pushed the fix in our packaging org, which has resolved the issue.
Thanks to everyone with your response and comments.

Comment: Looks, to me, like you have a class that used to implement `Schedulable` and now does not, and that class has been scheduled to execute on your packaging org. NB: There's no need to convert to mdapi format to deploy to your packaging org; simply use the correct "deploy source" sfdx command.

Comment: Thanks Phil for your comment. We haven't made any changes to ```Schedulable``` classes. Also as it is packaging org, we do not do any testing or data changes in the org. So there are no scheduled jobs in the org.

Comment: We are also seeing this error, we are about to jump on a call with Salesforce Support and we'll share any update they provide. Seems like a general bug they introduced.

Comment: @Jose any updates so far? Curious about what SF support says

Comment: Hey @kurunve what Vinay commented below, the issue has been identified as a [bug](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000tJnh9/managed-package-developer-orgs-are-sometimes-getting-error-interface-systemschedulable-relationship-must-be-maintained-while-editing-apex)

Answer (score 2):

This has been identified as bug with salesforce with no workaround.

Kindly review KI details [here](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000tJnh9/managed-package-developer-orgs-are-sometimes-getting-error-interface-systemschedulable-relationship-must-be-maintained-while-editing-apex).

Comment: Thanks Vinay, Salesforce has fixed and pushed the fix to our packaging org now.